# Why is there Whitespace at the Bottom of My Tab Area?

Tags: jquery, html, css, background, tabs

My jQuery UI tabs' DIV has a background-color set, but it flashes once the page loads from filling the element to about 6/7ths full.  Also, I tried setting the background-color WITHOUT jQuery (the result was the same); I was merely testing alternate solutions.  Here is my HTML (w/ JS):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Agile</title>

<link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script>

var head_conf = { head: "js" };

</script>

<script type="text/Javascript" src="./js/head.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

js.js(
    
    { jquery: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" },
    { tools: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js" },
    { extras: "./js/extras.js" }
    
);

js.ready( function() {
        
        var jFiles = $("#files");
        
        jFiles.tabs( { closable: true } ).show().css("background-color", "#EEEEEE");
        
} );

</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="files">
    
    <ul>
        
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
        
    </ul>
    
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

and CSS:

```css
body,
html {
    
    height: 97%;
    
}

body {
    
    font-size: 10px;
    
}

li > a {
    
    padding: 6px !important;
    
}

#files {
    
    display: none;
    
    height: 100%;
    
    min-height: 300px;
    
}

.ui-icon-circle-close {
    
    opacity: 0.4;
    
}

.ui-icon-circle-close:hover {
    
    opacity: 1;
    
}

.ui-tabs-nav {
    
    min-height: 30px;
    
}

.ui-tabs-panel {
    
    height: 95%;
    
}
```

Here is a picture of the situation:

[image: wtf]

Comment: Try setting the height: of your `<ul>` element.

Comment: do you have any live example for the above problem?

Comment: If I add height:50px to the <ul> element (way too much, but it illustrates the solution), I see the rest of the tab - the selected tab is slightly taller than the others. Is that the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @MattH No, I'm sorry.  See the giant white space at the bottom of the page?  I don't see why it's there.  Even with pure CSS setting the background color for the DIV, it doesn't work.

Comment: Got it - looks like that's an effect of your ui-widget usage. I glanced at the CSS for the element but nothing jumps out as to why it's there. That's a tricky one. You should update your question to make the problem clear, e.g. "How do I get rid of the white space at the bottom" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#files ul {
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I got it thanks to you.  I defined it like so:

    #files.ui-widget{
     
     background:#eee !important
    
    }